# Use Django Forms just to verify HTML form data and not for rendering

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

Im my project I have used normal html forms with custom formatting and in various places included CRUD operation using table also. I was wondering is there any way to pass the data from my html forms to Django Forms for validation, as I can't use Django Forms for rendering the forms on my page due to the complexity of the project but I still would like to use the built in validations of Django Forms before I insert the data into Database.

For Example: I have 2 Models one Course and a Subject. So when creating a course there is an editable [Table](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tutorialrepublic.com%2Fsnippets%2Fdesigns%2Ftable-with-add-and-delete-row-feature.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tutorialrepublic.com%2Fsnippets%2Fpreview.php%3Ftopic%3Dbootstrap%26file%3Dcrud-data-table-for-database-with-modal-form&tbnid=Js1n2ALPrrDsaM&vet=12ahUKEwjzxqCGzIPqAhUsMLcAHQTTDj4QMygDegUIARCsAQ..i&docid=E_xStxMDC0FYCM&w=728&h=300&q=crud%20operation%20in%20html%20table&client=safari&ved=2ahUKEwjzxqCGzIPqAhUsMLcAHQTTDj4QMygDegUIARCsAQ) beneath the form where you can insert, update and delete Subjects related to the course, and I use Ajax to send form and table data to view. Now in view I have to validate Course and each Subject[Each row in table id one Subject Object] before inserting in into database.

As I need the table I can't use Django form there.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking... are you saying you have an html page with a NON django form, and want to use django forms for validations? Why not validate it on the view?

Comment: You can always try form = DjangoForm(request.POST)

Comment: Yes you can, but if there are any errors found there will be no way to pass the form errors back to html since you are not rendering the form. Just custom validate everything in the view and pass custom errors back to the html

Comment: Yes you can use forms just for validation. And the errors *can* also be displayed on the template. You just need to pass the `form` object to the template. There's a section in the documentation just about rendering forms manually: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

Comment: But I think according to his question he isn't using the form template. Maybe I misunderstood what he meant @xyres

Comment: Yes I have an HTML page with a NON Django form, and I was wondering if I can use Django Forms for validation so I don't have to write the validation logic myself.